# How do I redeem my free PS3 games for the "Welcome Back" post outage?

Tags: ps3

I sent myself a reminder to get on the Playstation Network and download my free games before the 30 day window expires, but I don't see any way to do it.  I went as far as looking up Dead Nation in the store but it is still $14.99.

Will there be a big obvious button to press to get these games or am I going to have to keep fishing around the store waiting for a few titles to show up as free?

EDIT:  I can't answer this, since it is closed, but I keep getting badges for thousands of views, so clearly people want the answer:

Sign in, go to the store, and it is the second menu item on the left.  It also appears in the rotation of ads on the right side.  You can use this to get both PS3 and PSP games.

You must explicitly redeem the PlayStation Plus for 30 days and the trial starts when you redeem it.  They say it won't auto-renew, but then the boilerplate says it *will* auto renew.  You can disable that explicitly in Account management / Transaction Management.

Comment: Here in Germany, the store is still not available.

Comment: Ironic that my first closed question (for "not generally applicable") also earned me the "popular question" badge for getting over 1000 views.  When the Welcome Back program is active I will update the question with an answer if it is not blindingly obvious.

Comment: you can always make a case for the question to be re-opened in [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Juan, I appreciate that it can be off-topic regardless of its popularity.  In about 30 days it will be of no use to anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I've read says that although the store is back up, the Welcome Back programme isn't active yet. I'm sure they'll make it fairly obvious when it is.

Comment: http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/06/01/playstation-store-is-available-and-updated-now/ - "You may have noticed that the content promised as part of the Welcome Back offer is not yet live."

Comment: Thanks for the source, I was on my phone when I responded so couldn't spend time searching :)

Comment: it's available in the US now.